# Markup for Sphinx formatting of argparse

Tags: python-sphinx, argparse, restructuredtext

I am using Sphinx/reStructuredText to create HTML and PDF docs for a project and am including the output of the argparse help for the command line tools. At the moment I am pasting the output in manually but plan at some point to switch to autogenerated output.

The problem is that while the formatting is fine for named parameters (like -x or --xray) it doesn't work well on positional parameters. It looks like the absence of a leading '-' on the parameter name is confusing it. The output looks like normal text without the neat indentation etc.

So my question is, does there exist markup that would force formatting the positional parameters as if they had leading '-' characters? If not, could someone suggest where in the docs or code I should start looking to put something together myself?

Comment: Perhaps you can use an option list; see http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#option-lists.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the link - this is what I am trying to get working, except that instead of the normal use case of "-a, --arg_one" format, I have a positional parameter that argparse displays as simply "arg_one". What I'd like is some markup that says "hey, pretend that the next word starts with a "-".

Comment: How about simply copying the argparse help output verbatim into a code-block?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good fallback if necessary. But I am hoping to take advantage of Sphinx's pretty printing that works well for the optional parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use *sphinx-argparse* extension.
It does not use output of *argparse* help, but it instead introspects *argparse* parser itself and provides proper *sphinx* markup for both positional arguments and options, formatting them as definition list with proper labels.

Sub-commands are also easily handled.

http://sphinx-argparse.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

It will also cover you needs in:

> plan at some point to switch to autogenerated output